# read the last line of multi-line string separated by line feeds

Tags: vb.net

i have a variable held in memory as string with several lines. the name of the variable is 'trace2'

i.e.

```
Dim trace2 As String
```

instead of reading every line i just want to read the last line.

all i can find are examples of reading a text file, but not from a variable held in memory

TIA

---

added

---

i tried this, but i dont like it because i dont want to create a file

```
      Dim fileNameAndPath As String = "0trace2.txt"

        Dim fileContent As String
        Dim fileLines() As String

        Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(fileNameAndPath)

            fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd
            fileLines = fileContent.Split(System.Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray)
            If fileLines.Count >= 2 Then

                For lineNumber As Integer = fileLines.GetUpperBound(0) - 1 To fileLines.GetUpperBound(0)

                    MsgBox(fileLines)
                Next

            End If

            sr.Close()
        End Using
```

Comment: Show what you've done.

Comment: fileLines(fileLines.count-1) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply `File.ReadLines` and `Enumerable.Last`?

```
Dim lastLine As String = File.ReadLines(fileNameAndPath).LastOrDefault() ' is Nothing if the file is empty
```

[`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) does not need to read all lines before it can start processsing, so it's cheap in terms of memory consumption.

If you already have the `string`:

```
Dim lastLine = trace2.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None).LastOrDefault()
```

Comment: i dont want to read a file. i don want to save a file to the HD to read. i already have the data loaded in a var named trace2. it has 800 lines i use for other purposes. but for this part of the program i need to isolate and read only the last line

Comment: i am getting a blank line at the end of the file ... how do i configure it for the next to the last line? thanks for the reply

Comment: Just change `StringSplitOptions.None` to `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx